# Invoke RxJava2 cancellable/disposable from correct thread

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am implementing an observable that emmits lines from a `Resource`.

The problem is that this resource really does not like being closed from a different thread that it was created on (it kills a puppy and throws an exception when this happens).

When I dispose the subscription, the resource `Cancellable`/`Disposable` is invoked from the `main` thread, while the observable was subscribed on `Schedulers.io()`.

Here is the Kotlin code:

```
fun lines(): Observable<String> =
        Observable.create { emitter ->
            val resource = NetworkResource()
            emitter.setCancellable {
                resource.close() // <-- main thread :(
            }
            try {
                while (!emitter.isDisposed)
                    emitter.onNext(resource.readLine()) // <-- blocked here!
            } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                emitter.tryOnError(ioe) // <-- this also triggers the cancellable
            }
        }

val disposable = lines()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { Log.i(TAG, "Line: $it" }

disposable.dispose() // <-- main thread :)
```

**Question**: Is it possible to invoke the `Cancellable` from the correct* thread, taking into account that the subscribing thread is blocked on `resource.readLine()`?

*Correct thread meaning the one from `subscribeOn(Schedures.io())`.

**EDIT**: I am afraid this question does not have a correct answer, unless `resource.close()` is made thread-safe or some kind of polling on `resource.dataReady` is implemented so that the thread is not blocked.

Comment: I think you should try the `unsubscribeOn` method to define where the `cancellable` will be executed.

Comment: @masp thank you for your comment but it doesn't work. See my comment on the answer below. Any other idea?

Answer (score 3):

`Schedulers.io()` manages a thread pool, so it may or may not use the same thread to dispose your resource. You will have to use a custom scheduler and the `unsubscribeOn()` operator to ensure your `Observable` is subscribed and unsubscribed on the same thread. Something like:

```
Scheduler customScheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

val disposable = lines()
        .unsubscribeOn(customScheduler)
        .subscribeOn(customScheduler)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { Log.i(TAG, "Line: $it" }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. The thread from the executor is blocked at `resource.readLine()`, so scheduling the cancellable with `unsubscribeOn(...)` never calls it because the thread is never released. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind delaying the call to `NetworkResource#close` a little bit, why not just

```
    fun lines(): Observable<String> =
            Observable.create { emitter ->
                val resource = NetworkResource()
                try {
                    while (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        emitter.onNext(resource.readLine())
                    }
                    resource.close()
                } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                    emitter.tryOnError(ioe)
                }
            }
```

But there is still an issue with this: In case of an `IOException` nobody will ever call `NetworkResource#close` (also in your example from the question, I think).

Attempt to fix this:

```
    fun lines(): Observable<String> =
            Observable.create { emitter ->
                val resource = NetworkResource()
                try {
                    while (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                        emitter.onNext(resource.readLine()) 
                    }
                } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                    emitter.tryOnError(ioe)
                } finally {
                    resource.close() // try-catch here, too?
                }
            }
```

or using "Kotlin-Try-With-Resources" function `use`

```
    fun lines(): Observable<String> =
            Observable.create { emitter ->
                NetworkResource().use { resource ->
                    try {
                        while (!emitter.isDisposed) {
                            emitter.onNext(resource.readLine())
                        }
                    } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                        emitter.tryOnError(ioe)
                    }
                }
            }
```

I hope, this helps. I wish you a nice weekend.

Comment: Hey Peti, thank you for your answer, but it doesn't solve the issue because the thread will still be stuck at `resource.readLine()`, so the `emitter.isDisposed` flag won't be checked until a line is received, which could be a while. I am afraid that there isn't an answer unless it is safe to call `resource.close()` from another thread. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Yeah, the dedicated IO thread will call `close` delayed... This is the "If you don't mind delaying the call" introduction of this answer :-) But is this really an issue? Because `NetworkResource` seems to be blocking, the dedicated IO thread is anyway somehow "wasted" during the lifetime of an ongoing `lines()` subscription...

Comment: You are right, the thread being "wasted" is a small issue, what I am more worried about is not being able to close the underlying network connection.

Answer (score 0):

What about taking an alternative path?

a) by **making `NetworkResource` thread-safe** (if you are in control of the sourcecode)

or

b) by **wrapping `NetworkResource` with an "agent"**? With "agent" I mean a proxy which uses internally a dedicated thread which does all the interaction with `NetworkResource` (constructing, readLine, close, ...)

Comment: Thanks again Peti. About a) I can't control it, about b) already tried it.